# How to add values into Matlab matrix and not overwrite it

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have to insert values from a for loop into the matrix, but the values are all the time getting overwritten, so only last values are added into the matrix. What is the way to add every value to the matrix inside a for loop without overwriting? I need to write `start1` and `stop1` values into the matrix. I just can't find the way how to do it.

My code is this:

```
    %reading the file
list = fopen('file.txt','r');
C=cell(size(list))

for k=1:length(list)
    content = fgets(list(k)) 
    d= strsplit(content,',')

    for n=1:length(d) % d contains 25 elements
            B = zeros(n,1); % preallocate, results output
            y=d{n} 
            z= strsplit(y,' ') 
            start=z{1} 
            stop=z{2} 
            start1 = str2num(start) 
            stop1 = str2num(stop)
            B = [start1,stop1] %write to the matrix
```

end

Comment: Look at the beginning and end of the second `for` loop. Of course it's overwriting.  What is your desired result?  Can you also show us a sample of the text file you are reading in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to define its location in B

`B(n,1:2) = [start1,stop1];`

of course you must replace `B = zeros(n,1);` with `B = zeros(n,2);`